# how to set the RHOME before import rpy?

Tags: python, r, rpy2, setting

I am trying to set up a tool on a web server. Since there are different versions of R, I want to specify it before I import rpy2. I found the following commands from the previous discussion. But it returns me "ImportError: No module named rpy_options". Anyone knows the problem?

```
from rpy_options import set_options
set_options(RHOME=''…')
```

Following shows the system and the versions of software I am using. Of course, besides these versions there are older version python and R on the server, but I am tying to use the latest ones.

- System: CentOS release 5.7
- Python version: 2.7.8,
- R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10),
- rpy2 version: 2.4.3

Thanks

Comment: Would setting RHOME with os solve the problem?  Looking at the source of rpy2.rinterface, I also think that rpy2 uses R_HOME instead of RHOME. `os.environ['R_HOME'] = 'RVersionLocation'`

Comment: `rpy_option` is for the older version `rpy` not for `rpy2`. Do what @charles suggest before `import rpy2` should get you there.

Comment: @cdeterman where can i find 'RVersionLocation' in `os.environ['R_HOME'] = 'RVersionLocation'` pls guide me on this